# Adding nodes to LinkedList<T> in foreach

Tags: .net, foreach, linked-list

Can I safely add nodes to LinkedList container inside foreach statement? Is there any difference if I used while loop? Or it is never allowed and can cause some problems?

```
foreach(var node in myList)
{
    if(condition)
        myList.AddLast(new MyNode());
}
```

Will it **always** work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't modify a collection while you're enumerating over it.

From the [docs for `LinkedList<T>.GetEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f2kh1bt.aspx):

> An enumerator remains valid as long as
>   the collection remains unchanged. If
>   changes are made to the collection,
>   such as adding, modifying, or deleting
>   elements, the enumerator is
>   irrecoverably invalidated and its
>   behavior is undefined.

In practice I believe it will always throw an `InvalidOperationException`, despite the behaviour officially being undefined.

EDIT: You asked in a comment whether a `while` loop would help... a while loop using `GetEnumerator`/`MoveNext`/`Current` wouldn't, but this will:

```
LinkedListNode<MyNode> current = myList.First;
while (current != null)
{
    if (condition) // use current.Value to get the value
    {
        myList.AddLast(new MyNode());
    }
    current = current.Next;
}
```

As far as I'm aware, that's entirely safe and predictable. You can always ask a node for its next node. If you happen to be looking at the tail node and add another one, you'll get the new tail node when you ask for "next".

If that doesn't help, please give us more details about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Entirely safe is a stretch, endless loop and OOM if the new node matches the condition.

Answer (score 2):

No, enumerator object remembers internal version of owning collection. After collection is modified - version changed, so foreach will fail.

Comment: +1 For peeking in with reflector to see how the enumerators were implementing the check :)

Answer (score 1):

While iterating over a collection with the `foreach` statement, you cannot modify it. Thus, adding items will result in a compiler error.

Comment: You can use a `while` loop to loop over the collection. You will not receive a compiler error when doing this, but be careful not to write an infinite loop - which can happen if new `MyNode()` fulfills `condition`.

Comment: It *won't* result in a compiler error. The code given will compile with no problem. It will throw an exception at execution time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Oops - I just remembered Visual Studio complain about this code and thought it would be a compiler error ... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add them to a new list. Then at the end, outside the **foreach** use **.addrange()** to append the new ones to the original list.